# How do I rebind keyboard shortcuts in VS Code's terminal?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, key-bindings

I'm running VS Code on macOS and would like to swap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> keys, but **only** in the integrated terminal. Is there a way I can do this?

Context: I'm an ex-Windows user now running macOS, and all my muscle memory is based around <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. As such, I've swapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> in my macOS keyboard settings, which allows me to e.g. copy text as I'd expect using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Unfortunately it seems that terminal applications on Mac *do* actually use the real <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, e.g. using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to send `SIGINT`. My global key-swap now makes that <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which is icky.

iTerm allows me to swap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> *back* again, and I'd like to do the same in VS Code - but only in its integrated terminal.

Answer (score 3):

So far my best option has been to rebind individual keystrokes in `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "\u0003"
    },
    "when": "terminalFocus && !terminalTextSelected"
}
```

This works, and the set of control characters I'd have to get through is smaller (I'd guess Ctrl + C, Z, D). But this is still not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

If there aren't too many of them it might be easier to change the shortcuts you frequently use (e.g. Cut, Copy, Paste) rather than remap the modifiers.

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts
[image]

[image]

This might make it less confusing to make use of other Mac shortcuts that use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> but maybe this isn't what you are looking for though.

Comment: I considered this, but there are a LOT of shortcuts (document commands, browser navigation, various IDEs and tools), and I'd be stuck on that treadmill for a long time. The global <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> swap has largely worked well for me, except in occasional cases like this.

Comment: For my basic usgae this solution is great!